# How to prevent my div from moving with expansion panel

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I’m trying to make a visualisation like this:

[image: Visualisation]

I used the built in `card` and `card-column`s of bootstrap. But when I expand a panel, all of my `<div>`s are moving randomly:

[image: Result]

I would like the other expansion panels to not move when I open one. Here is an example: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-bootstrap-css-nevm5w?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: The angular & JS code in your blitz is irrelevant to your current problem. Please provide a *static* [mcve] as an SO snippet so we can test your code ourselves

Comment: How is the angular code irrelevant to my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been testing your stackblitz code and the "problem" is at the line 8:

```
<div class="card-columns">
```

Exactly at the class name, 'card-columns' is a predefined class that maybe is in BootStrap predefined classes.

My suggestion is to remove this class and use another alternative, like a `flex-layout`.
Or use html columns.

I've forked your stackblitz code and solved using html columns:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-bootstrap-css-qmrzcm

Next step is to add your custom paddings between each columns.

Comment: Thank you very much